# Apache NiFi in Docker and Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi, minify

I'm trying to deploy Apache NiFi in a Docker container on EC2 Instance. Only 2 ports (80 and 443) are open at the moment and I don't have rights to change it.

I've managed to start NiFi:

```
sudo docker run --name nifi   -p 8080:8080   -d   apache/nifi:latest
```

Here is my nginx config:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    upstream nifi {
        server 0.0.0.0:8080;
        }
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nifi;
                proxy_set_header Origin http://nifi;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment NiFi works and I can access it via IP of the instance. `proxy_set_header Origin http://nifi;` setting fixed a problem with uploading templates to the service.

The problem is that I can't configure any processor at all. Every time, when I click on "configure" I get this error:

```
Unable to communicate with NiFi
Please ensure the application is running and check the logs for any errors.
```

[image]

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

I can't see anything useful in the logs. Once an error about not using HTTPS has appeared, but I think it's not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of fiddling with Docker, Nginx and NiFi, I've found the issue.
When I've opened network logs in a browser, I've noticed that Nifi was sending a request to 0.0.0.0 or nifi (the name of upstream).

[image]

I had to set `proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost` in my Nginx config file and it worked like a charm. I used public IP of my server, maybe I'll switch to domain name later.

The main problem with this issue was in the lack of logs: I've checked all logs of nifi and nginx and there was nothing interesting. I'm still wondering if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Having similar issue here brother. What IP did you pass for X-ProxyHost? Seems like processor configure window never opens, i can see it spinning and eventually gives the unable to communicate error

Comment: I had to set external ip address of my server, I think

Comment: Hey, by server do you mean the host ip? or the container ip of nifi? nginx?

Comment: host ip, so nifi could think it is not proxied

Comment: im afraid still didnt help for me. Let me know if you have any thoughts on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922227/nifi-on-docker-behind-nginx-processor-configure-not-opening . thanks

Comment: @StrangerThinks I don't have access to my work setup atm, but I think I will be able to send you an answer tomorrow

Comment: Fixed it. I had to set it to "localhost" or loopback for XProxy to work properly. Also set x-proxy-context path accordingly