# Nifi on docker behind nginx processor configure not opening

Tags: docker, nginx, apache-nifi, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Followed guide ( https://michalklempa.com/2019/04/nifi-registry-nginx-proxy-tls-basic-auth/ ) to set up nginx basic auth, however instead of proxy for nifi-registry I set it up for nifi. Auth is working and page is accessible but somehow processor configure window not opening. The issue is due to nginx since direct access to nifi through HTTP exposed ports works ,just not behind nginx proxy.

below is the config I am using:

```
server {
  listen 9988 ssl;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html;

  server_name _;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/server_cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/server_key.pem;

  ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client_cert.pem;
  ssl_verify_client optional;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  # enables server-side protection from BEAST attacks
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # Disabled insecure ciphers suite. For example, MD5, DES, RC4, PSK
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:@STRENGTH";

  # -!MEDIUM：exclude encryption cipher suites using 128 bit encryption.
  # -!LOW：   exclude encryption cipher suites using 64 or 56 bit encryption algorithms
  # -!EXPORT： exclude export encryption algorithms including 40 and 56 bits algorithms.
  # -!aNULL：  exclude the cipher suites offering no authentication. This is currently the anonymous DH algorithms and anonymous ECDH algorithms.
  # These cipher suites are vulnerable to a "man in the middle" attack and so their use is normally discouraged.
  # -!eNULL：exclude the "NULL" ciphers that is those offering no encryption.
  # Because these offer no encryption at all and are a security risk they are disabled unless explicitly included.
  # @STRENGTH：sort the current cipher list in order of encryption algorithm key length.

  location / {
    if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
      set $auth_basic off;
    }
    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
      set $auth_basic "Restricted Content. Please provide Nifi Authentication:";
    }

    auth_basic $auth_basic;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/nginx.htpasswd;

    proxy_pass    http://172.18.0.77:8181/; # actual container ip/port of nifi
    proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-User     $remote_user;
    proxy_set_header   Authorization        "";
    proxy_set_header   X-ProxyScheme        $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-ProxyHost          $hostname;
    proxy_set_header   X-ProxyPort          $server_port;
    proxy_set_header   X-ProxyContextPath   "/";
  }
}
```

I tried passing container ip of nifi/host/nginx for X-ProxyHost but instead of giving "Unable to communicate to nifi" immediately it spins for a while and eventually gives the same error. What needs to be modified here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx noob here!
After much fiddling with multiple ip/hostname combinations I was able to fix it with below config changes.
Had to add nifi env properties to the docker-compose:

```
environment:
  - NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_HOST=<private ip of nifi container e.g. 172.18.0.77>
  - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/
  - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=<private ip of nifi container>
  - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8181
```

And for nginx config: modified proxy_set_header to "localhost" (since nginx server needed proxyHost defined as loopback server):

```
proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost localhost;
```

Hope this helps someone scratching their head who are in the same boat :)