# NiFi 1.19 keeps restarting within Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, docker-desktop

I have Docker Desktop on Windows 10 and I run Apache NiFi 1.19 within container.

NiFi keeps restarting, by itself, without giving any useful log message, exception message, or whatever I can trace back with.

[image]

Any ideas what can be going wrong? I have tried many things.. including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773809/1553537), but nothing helped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, so the problem was built-in **Hyper-V backend** of the Docker (i.e. the default VM environment that comes with Docker Desktop).

I just opted for `Use the WSL 2 based engine` choice and problem went away.

From the Docker Desktop dashboard, go to `settings` and in the `General` tab, select "Use the WSL 2 based enginge":

[image]